# symfon 1.4 load different routing.yml based on url parameter inside a plugin

Tags: configuration, routes, load, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

I have a plugin and i need to load a different routing.yml file based on a variable in the query string.

Example:

```
if($request->getParameter('page'){
 // use routingPage.yml
}
else{
 // use another routing.yml
}
```

So, If the page parameter in url the url_for('@route1'), will return one url, else the same url_for('@route1') would return other url.

How can override the rouing.yml loading mechanism to do what I want?

Comment: I built a system that does this for a Symfony 1.4 project, but it is *super* complicated.  I ended up having to redo Symfony's routing configuration handler from top to bottom; it's just not designed to be overridden in this way.  If there's a simpler way of accomplishing what you need, I would suggest going with that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application can have only *one* `routing.yml` (of course it can be overrided by other plugins).

The reason for this is quite simple: If you want to use multiple routing files (say `routing1.yml` and `routing2.yml`), and they both have a route called `route1`, which redirects to `controller1/action` and `controller2/action` respectively.
Maybe you would be able to switch it in the view, and go to `controller1/action` in the one case and `controller2/action` in the other. But then: when a new request arrives, and the front controller is determining which controller / action to execute: how does it now which `routing.yml` to use?

So I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I would go for two routes in your `routing.yml`, and select the route based on your view parameters.